# error Cannot query field "allStrapiArticles" on type "Query"

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I've just started my first project with Strapi and Gatsby. After just upgrading to Gatsby CLI 3.0, I'm getting the following error:

`Cannot query field "allStrapiArticles" on type "Query"`

My entire file:

```
import React from "React"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Navbar from "../components/navbar"
import Footer from "../components/footer"

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => (
    <div>
        <Navbar />
    <h1>Articles</h1>
    <p>Colleciton of Photo Editorials</p>
    <ul>
        {data.allStrapiArticles.edges.map(document => (
            <li key={document.node.id}>
                <h2>
                    <Link to={`/${document.node.id}`}>{document.node.Title}</Link>
                </h2>
                <p>{document.node.Snippet}</p>
            </li>
        ))}
        </ul>
        <Footer />
    </div>
)

export default IndexPage

export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query IndexQuery {
        allStrapiArticles {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    Title
                    Snippet
                }
            }
        }
    }
    `
```

And my schema from Strapi is as follows:

```
type Articles {
  id: ID!
  created_at: DateTime!
  updated_at: DateTime!
  Title: String
  Snippet: String
  Content: String
  category: Category
  published_at: DateTime
  image(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [UploadFile]
  tags(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Tags]
}
```

I did initially have an issue with this due to using the singular 'Article' but had corrected that to the plural, and I also noted this is all case sensitive and require the capitalised 'Title' and 'Snippet'. But as I said, I had got this working just fine before upgrading to 3.0 and I can't see how the CLI would impact this.

Has there been a breaking change in that version that I have missed?

Comment: Could  you repalce 'allStrapiArticles' with 'allStrapiArticle' and see if it works. Also just to be sure does the user(authenticated/public) that is sending the request , has the access to "find" and "findOne" on the Article content type?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest downgrading to `v2` until all plugins and dependencies adapt their code to the current stable `v3`. Gatsby just recently released the `v3`, as you know, and its code works perfectly for the "native" use-case sourcing, or in other words, when gathering data from markdowns, JSONs, etc.

All plugin-related workaround, or when fetching data from an outer CMS, which always requires a plugin, the code is strictly dependant on the plugin's implementation so, until Strapi (in this case) doesn't update the code, you won't be able to use the `v3` of Gatsby without facing error, issues or caveats.